# OpenGL - drawing polygon on mouse click, polygon is always on to the right

Tags: c++, opengl

For one of my classes I'm creating a simple paint program with OpenGL and one of the first steps is to make a left mouseclick create a polygon on the window. I get it to draw it but the polygon always ends up about a third across the window to the right of the position where I click

My mouseclick code is ...

```
//function called when mouse is clicked
void mouseClick(int button, int state, int x, int y){

    float ptr1[3] = { x-size, y-size, 0 };
    float ptr2[3] = { x-size, y+size, 0 };
    float ptr3[3] = { x+size, y+size, 0 };
    float ptr4[3] = { x+size, y-size, 0 };

  if( button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN){//if the left mouse button     is     clicked   
    glColor3f ( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0); //set color to white ( remove later)
    glOrtho (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0); //sets the window coordinates?
    glBegin (GL_POLYGON); //start drawing a polygon
             glVertex3fv (ptr1);
     glVertex3fv (ptr2);
     glVertex3fv (ptr3);
     glVertex3fv (ptr4);
glEnd();
    glFlush(); //flushes all commands to ensure polygon is drawn
  }
  //glutPostRedisplay( );
}
```

Can anyone see any obvious faults? Size is a float = to 32 but I feel like that's irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: What are your x and y coordinates? Your glOrtho() call is setting up the drawing area to be defined from 0 to 1 in both directions. Are your x and y coordinates coming back between -0.5 and 0.5 or something like that?

Comment: Oh ok. Im just clicking. But my window is 800 by 600 so im going to change ortho to match that. Opengl is.brand new to me. So i didn't even know what exactly ortho did

Comment: Well, if you're seeing things being drawn, then your x and y are obviously close to being correct. I wouldn't just change glOrtho() without having more information about what coordinates you're passing in. You could start by printing the x and y values and see what they are before making any changes. See if you can understand why they are what they are first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize your X and Y coordinates of mouse in to your ortho... for that you can do this 
x1 = x/weight of your screen
y1 = y/height of your screen
x1 and y1 new variables and x , y are mouse arguments...